# import data from mysql to excel files using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, excel, hibernate, spring-tool-suite

"can someone please tell me how to import data from MySQL database and export in excel sheets.
please explain with all the steps and code."

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. By having entity, repository in hand
you can use Apache Poi library to create a excel structure in service class.

This is a good example:
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/export-data-to-excel-example
The trick is mostly in controller and setting Headers.

Comment: this code include spring boot, can we do this without the help of spring boot??